# pointer-event none only for middle click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a big iframe that embeds an app within the main website.  The iframe uses `postMessage` to tell the parent how big the iframe should be, depending on the page, so there is no scrolling inside the iframe, it is all done on the parent page.

If the mouse is hovered over the iframe, scroll works fine and the parent scrolls, but middle mouse click does nothing, whereas if the mouse is not hovered over the iframe, middle click works fine.

Is there a way to propagate middle mouse click to the top frame, or ignore pointer events only for middle click in the iframe? Thanks.